# Setting multiple DataContexts in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datacontext

How to set multiple dataContexts? I have Model and ViewModel - I can write just **one** data context in XAML in Windows.DataContext for example

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <v:FacebookViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

and then in constructor or on button click I can just write `_faceViewModel = (FacebookViewModel)this.DataContext;`. That will set dataContext.

My question: I have 2 ViewModels and I want, on a click of a button or if you have some better idea, to change datacontext for my second ViewModel TwitterViewModel - how do to that? I'm learning WPF now and I'm really new at this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it programatically using DataContext property. I think the better way is to write a DataTemplates for your ViewModels and set them in the needed container(if you viewmodels have different appearances). If your vm have the same appeaances, then may be you shoud think about encapsulation different logic behide one viewmodel.

```
class VM 
{
  private IVMImplementation manager = null;

  public VM(IVMImplementation manager) { this.manager = manager; }

  public SetManager(IVMImplementation manager) { this.manager = manager; }
}
class TwitterVMManager : IVMImplementation  {}
class FacebookVMManager : IVMImplementation  {}
```

I believe it will work faster than change datacontext..